# I Have a Textbox in vba Access. When I set the ControlSource property Using Design it works. But if i try to do it programatically it does not

Tags: ms-access, vba

I Created a form in Access with two TextBox.The property RecordSource of the Form and the ControlSource of one of the textbox have an initial property set up.

When the user clicks a button located on the same form, the RecordSource property of the form as well as the ControlSource property of a textbox should change to a different Source.

I tested the Source(the one that should change when the button is click) of the ControlSource by setting it as the initial property. But when I tried to do it Programatically it doesnot work. Any help would be appreciated. Im using Access 2000. The code is shown below:

Code Behind

```
Private Sub Dry_Type_Click()
  Me.RecordSource = "Engineering Schedule2"
  Dim strcatnum As String
  Dim param As String
  strcatnum = "5203"
  param = "Catalog Number Log " & strcatnum

  catnumbox.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]""," & param & ",""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])"
End Sub
```

Comment: There might be some auto-generated code that the designer puts in another place.  I suggest trying to find that code and make sure you are doing similar things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

catnumbox.ControlSource = "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]"", ""Catalog Number Log 5203"", ""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])"

Comment: Thanks For the help that worked ! What if the number '5203' had to be change several times. I was trying dim catnum, catnum = "5204". And then ........"Catalog Number Log " & catnum"... but it gave me an error. Cam you help me with that part please

Comment: you need to use double-quotes inside a quoted string: VBA interprates it to be a single quote in the result. It is easier to build a vraible part outside: param="Catalog Number Log " & catnum, and thenuse the param string: "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]"", param, ""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])"

Comment: @ Gene, I tried The code that you suggested for using catnum but it did not work. It does not gives me an error but if I click on the properties of the text button this is what I see : =DLookUp("[Catalog Number]",param,"[Sequence No]=" & [Sequence Number])

Comment: oops! my bad: "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]"", " & param & ", ""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])"

Comment: Almost There Gene. I got the error The expression you entered containts invalid syntax. "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]""," & param & ",""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])" . If you can help me with this would be great

Comment: Let's start with the "param"? Is is syntaxed correctly? can you show it's value to me? You still need the double-quotes. If not in the "param" then back in the formula.

Comment: I Edited my question with what I'm doing. I have no idea what is wrong . I have never had to deal with Access 2000 or any VBA before. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: I suspect you need  "=DLookup(""[Catalog Number]"",""" & param & """,""[Sequence No]="" & [Sequence Number])"

Answer (score 1):

Most events are not fired when set by VBA. You ought to put the requirements in a procedure and call that procedure in any required events or procedures.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the ControlSource at run time. You can do it all at design time, without any VBA outside of the Control Source, and without the need to double any of your quotes.

Suppose your 5203 comes from a textbox txtLogNum. It could be bound or unbound.

At design time, set the ControlSource for catnumbox to:

```
=DLookup("[Catalog Number]", 
         "Catalog Number Log " & [txtLogNum], 
         "[Sequence No]=" & [Sequence Number])
```

Now, whenever [Sequence Number] or [txtLogNum] change, Access will re-evaluate catnumbox.

**EDIT - ANOTHER EXAMPLE ADDED**

If you don't want catnumbox to change until the user clicks [Dry Type], then at design time leave the ControlSource blank. The main reason to use an expression in a ControlSource is so that it recalculates automatically.

This VBA also addresses your comment about two combo boxes.

```
Private Sub Dry_Type_Click()
Dim LogTableName As String
Me.RecordSource = "Engineering Schedule2"
LogTableName = "Catalog Number Log " & _
               [cboLogNumPart1] & _
               [cboLogNumPart2]
catnumbox.Value = DLookup("[Catalog Number]", LogTableName, _
                          "[Sequence No]=" & [Sequence Number])
End Sub
```

What this ***won't*** do is to trigger any events or any recalculations that are based on the value of catnumbox.

Comment: The problem is that I have Initially set the ControlSource To a @ @Tom different table "Catalog NUmber Log" for cat numbers 3400 Then im going to have two combo boxes. The first combobox for the numbers 52,53,54,55. Each one of those numbers can have a combination with a second combobox with numbers 0-49. Example 5201...5049 . 5301...5349 etc...

Comment: If you don't want catnumbox to update until the user clicks [Dry Type], then set the control source to blank and simply calculate its new value directly in VBA without the extra level of complexity. I'll put the code in an edit to my answer.